# Can I use Log4j.xml configuration for SLF4J and Logback?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I have a project using `common-logging` and `log4j`, I want to change to use SLF4J + Logback. Is there any way to use existing `log4j.xml` for Logback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the logger implementation to logback, you should use a logback.xml config file (and its associated format).

Comment: @mavlarn and if your code uses SLF4j than configuration is the only thing you'd have to change

Comment: In Logback web there is a log4j.properties to logback.xml translator => http://logback.qos.ch/translator/

Answer (score 3):

There exists a log4j.properties to logback.xml migrator available online: http://logback.qos.ch/translator/

For log4j.xml files, there structure of logback.xml files is very similar. Thus, it should not be hard to migrate your log4j.xml to logback.xml ***manually***. If you run into trouble please post on the logback-user mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the slf4j api compatible replacements for commons-logging and log4j.

http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

basically you need to make sure that you have jcl-over-slf4j.jar and log4j-over-slf4j on the classpath and remove any copies of commons-logging.jar and log4j.jar. If you use maven, you'll probably want to add a lot of exclusions for this on libraries that pull these in.

I have no experience with logback so see above comment from polypiel for the log4j translator.